# In Ruby, is it possible to do arithmetic with symbols?

Tags: ruby, enums, symbols

In Ruby, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
days_of_week = %i(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday) 
today = :Sunday
today = today + 1
if today > :Saturday
    today = :Sunday
end
```

This gives me
'undefined method '+' for :Sunday:Symbol (NoMethodError)

Can I define a method somehow?

I've looked at various stack overflow questions on enums, and didn't see what I'm looking for, but it's a large volume of information to sort through.

Comment: You probably want to implement your own type here, a Ruby class, so you can override operators like `>` and define your own comparator. Then you can do `Day.sunday < Day.today` or some such.

Comment: "Can I define a method somehow?" – Yes, in Ruby you can define methods. Is that really your question?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag  "Is that really your question?"   No.  I already know that Ruby allows you to create methods. But I think my concern is clear in the question.  Is it not, to you?   I'd like to be friendly, but especially in writing, your question to me comes off as a bit grumpy, with no substantive information. You have a massive reputation number (congrats), and you've obviously contributed an enormous amount to this community, but I could wish your words were clearer here: What are you suggesting to me?  Does it seem worth nit-picking my question in this way?

Comment: _"something like this"_ – are symbols a strict requirement or do you just want a succinct solution that reads well?

Comment: @stefan A succinct solution that reads well.  Yes!  Symbols not a requirement.

Answer (score 4):

This code, as it is, does not work in ruby (as you noticed). Symbol `:Sunday` does not know that it's placed in an array, so adding a `1` to it does not make any sense.

You **can** compare symbols like that, but the results will surprise you. `:Wednesday` is greater than `:Thursday`, for example.

Why not just operate on indexes in the array. With integer indexes you can increment them and compare with expected results. Could look like this, for example:

```rb
today = days_of_week.index(:Friday)
puts "tomorrow is #{days_of_week[today + 1]}" # >> tomorrow is Saturday
```

Comment: This works, but involves a linear array search for every comparison. Probably doesn't matter, but it's certainly slower than using, for example, `MONDAY = 1; TUESDAY = 2; if MONDAY < TUESDAY` etc.

Comment: @user229044 "linear array search for every comparison" - nope, comparisons are "free", as are increments. `.index` is linear complexity, yes. I chose to initialize `today` this way to better show the link between `today` and the array.

Comment: Free-floating integer constants can work, but there are scenarios where we need an array of names. Populate a dropdown or something like that.

Comment: Any searching method is fast when there are 7 items in the array.

Comment: @engineersmnky: nah, one just needs to do a proper wrap-around, `tomorrow = (today + 1) % days_of_week.length`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You chose an example that doesn't involve a linear search, but this is a cherry picked example that doesn't do what OP asks for: Comparing two arbitrary symbols. To actually do what OP is asking for, you have to accept two symbols as input, perform a lookup for both, and compare the indices. The question is specifically about arithmetic with symbols as operands.

Comment: @user229044 To borrow a standard legal clause (which I have found applies liberally on SO): *"The Title of this Post is included for convenience and informational purposes only and shall neither affect the construction or interpretation of the Post nor be construed in such a way as to alter the substance of the contents of the Post itself."* In this case the actual content of the question does not suggest the need to compare two arbitrary symbols or perform arithmetic with them (regardless of the title)  but rather it poses a specific consideration resulting in what appears to be a XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

> This gives me `` undefined method `+' for :Sunday:Symbol (NoMethodError) ``
>
> Can I define a method somehow?

In Ruby, you can open existing classes and add methods to them. Although it's not recommended to patch classes you don't own – let alone core classes – it's absolutely possible:

```
class Symbol
  WEEKDAYS = %i(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday)

  def +(offset)
    wday = WEEKDAYS.index(self)
    return unless wday

    WEEKDAYS[(wday + offset) % WEEKDAYS.length]
  end
end

:Sunday + 2
#=> :Tuesday
```

---

A less invasive approach is to define a custom class:

```
class WeekDay
  attr_reader :name, :wday

  def initialize(name, wday)
    @name = name
    @wday = wday
  end

  alias to_s name
  alias inspect name
end
```

In addition to a `name`, each instance also knows its `wday` (0-6) which will simplify the lookup later on (so we don't have to scan the array to find the day's index).

For each day of the week I'd define a constant and also put all days in an array: (you could also use a loop and define them via [`const_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#const_set-method), I prefer to set them explicitly)

```
class WeekDay
  module DayConstants
    Sunday    = WeekDay.new('Sunday', 0)
    Monday    = WeekDay.new('Monday', 1)
    Tuesday   = WeekDay.new('Tuesday', 2)
    Wednesday = WeekDay.new('Wednesday', 3)
    Thursday  = WeekDay.new('Thursday', 4)
    Friday    = WeekDay.new('Friday', 5)
    Saturday  = WeekDay.new('Saturday', 6)
  end

  include DayConstants
  WEEKDAYS = [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday].freeze

  def +(offset)
    WEEKDAYS[(wday + offset) % WEEKDAYS.length]
  end
end
```

You might have wondered why I put the day constants in a separate module. It's so you can easily include them in your current namespace: (this is mostly cosmetic – you could just as well omit the `include` and write out `today = WeekDay::Sunday`)

```
include WeekDay::DayConstants

today = Sunday
today += 1
today #=> Monday

today += 4
today #=> Friday

today += 2
today #=> Sunday
```

To add comparison operators, you can include [`Comparable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Comparable.html) and implement `<=>`:

```
class WeekDay
  include Comparable

  def <=>(other)
    wday <=> other.wday if other.is_a?(WeekDay)
  end

  # ...
end
```

```
Friday > Wednesday
#=> true

Wednesday.between?(Monday, Friday)
#=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would create an index with as many entries as necessary to describe what you are trying to do.

Here is a hash of hashes to hold the index and next/prev logical day:

```
days_of_week = %i(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday)

idx=Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = {} }
days_of_week.each_with_index{ |e,i| 
    idx[e][:idx]=i
    idx[e][:next_day]=
        (i+1)==days_of_week.length ? days_of_week[0] : days_of_week[i+1]
    idx[e][:prev_day]=
        i==0 ? days_of_week[-1] : days_of_week[i-1]     
}

# {:Sunday=>{:idx=>0, :next_day=>:Monday, :prev_day=>:Saturday}, :Monday=>{:idx=>1, :next_day=>:Tuesday, :prev_day=>:Sunday}, :Tuesday=>{:idx=>2, :next_day=>:Wednesday, :prev_day=>:Monday}, :Wednesday=>{:idx=>3, :next_day=>:Thursday, :prev_day=>:Tuesday}, :Thursday=>{:idx=>4, :next_day=>:Friday, :prev_day=>:Wednesday}, :Friday=>{:idx=>5, :next_day=>:Saturday, :prev_day=>:Thursday}, :Saturday=>{:idx=>6, :next_day=>:Sunday, :prev_day=>:Friday}}
```

Then you can get the next day or previous day:

```
idx[:Tuesday][:next_day]
# Wednesday
idx[:Saturday][:next_day]
# Wraps around to Sunday
```

You can create a compare:

```
def cmp(x,y, idx)
    idx[x][:idx]<=>idx[y][:idx]
    end
```

So that `:Wednesday` is properly less than `:Thursday`

```
cmp(:Wednesday, :Thursday, idx)
-1
```

Or sort another array of symbols into the order of the index:

```
%i(Saturday Sunday Tuesday Thursday Wednesday Friday Monday).
sort_by{ |day| idx[day][:idx] } 
# [:Sunday, :Monday, :Tuesday, :Wednesday, :Thursday, :Friday, :Saturday]
```

Those types of function can be added to a class to represent the type of symbols you want to deal with.